# Scroll textboxes and set attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a smart solution for setting textareas attributes. I do have a lot of textareas at the page. Some are disabled and some are not. It depend on user logged in and selections made. All of the textareas are 'required' by custom class 'class="reqformtextbox validate[required]"',

What I want is to scroll/find textboxes and set its class to `class="reqformtextbox"`, effectively removing 'required' attribute for the textboxs which are currently **disabled** by 'disabled="disabled"' attribute.

Comment: `textbox` tag does not exists afaik in html, do yours have a `class` named like that?

Comment: Well it is 'textarea' tag. Sorry for confusion

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `enabeditable` is an attribute with boolean values (correct me if I'm wrong), the **jQuery** you want is:

```
$('textarea[enableditable=true]').attr('required', true);
```

`$('textarea[enableditable=true]')` will select all elements with tag `textarea` and attribute `enableditable=true`

`attr('required', true)` will add or replace attribute `required=true`.

**Javascript** doesn't have a one-line selector for html tag + attribute, but you can make a function that queries all elements by `getElementsByTagName()`, iterates them and returns a list with all elements having `getAttribute('enableditable') = true.

Comment: I can't select all disabled textareas with getElementsByTagName(). I can olny select all textareas. regardless of it's attribute

Comment: @OlegAgadjanyan I wrote you the `getAllElementsWithAttribute` function

Comment: Sorry for the mess but since my first post my task slightly changed and i have edited the question. now the requirement is to apply different class to disabled elements. The idea is the same though. removing 'required' attribute.

Comment: @ Alexandru....I m getting 'TypeError: all[i].getAttribute is not a function' error using the function

Comment: @OlegAgadjanyan just use the jquery solution, much easier to implement and understand.

Comment: Gents, I have solved the problem with Jquery. Thank you all for pointing me into the right direction.
`jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery('textarea[disabled="disabled"]').removeClass( "reqformtextbox validate[required]" ).addClass( "reqformtextbox" );
   
  }); `

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use jQuery to solve this.

Here is the example

```
$(function(){
   $("input[type=text]").attr("required","required");
});
```

Replace selector if you have any other selector. This will apply for all `textbox` in the page.

Comment: I'm affraid 'enabeditable' attribute doesn't exist . this is what i have in page source 
'<textarea id="jform_comments1" name="jform[comments1]" class="reqformtextbox" cols="32" rows="4"></textarea>'

Comment: this is currently disabled element
<textarea id="jform_coments2" name="jform[coments2]" class="reqformtextbox" disabled="disabled" cols="32" rows="4"></textarea>

Comment: Use this code `$("textarea:not(:disabled)").attr("required","required");`

Comment: `(function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {

   $('textarea[disabled=disabled]').addClass("reqformtextbox ");
   });  
});`
Is this the right way ? I need to apply class for all disabled textareas